# error: expected ')' before '<' token|

Tags: c++

I was implementing a String and was giving the definition in .h file. The code in String.h is the following:

```
#include<list>
class String
{
    public:
    String();//Constructor
    String(char * copy);//For converting CString to String
    const char *c_str(const String &copy);//For converting String to Cstring
    String(list<char> &copy);//Copying chars from list
    //Safety members
    ~String();
    String(const String &copy);
    void operator = (const String &copy);
    protected:
    int length;
    char *entries;
};
```

The error is mentioned in the subject. What is it that I am not following?

Comment: Your `operator=` is delcared incorrectly.  It should return a reference to self.

Comment: Who would store a string of characters in a list?? And does that `String(char * copy)` really modify the string it's copying from? And why is that member function to convert to a C string taking an argument?? _Who gave you such a header?_ It's hilarious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `std::` in front of `list<char>` :

```
String(std::list<char> &copy);
```

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola - lol. I wonder how much of his 11.1K rep is from using that album cover as his icon.

Comment: @T.E.D- coincidentally, i just changed my pic to dsotm yesterday.. perhaps my rep shall match his one day..

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola - I suppose I could test this theory by changing mine to a Wham! album cover and observe how much my rep drops.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed several of your issues at once:

```
#include <list>

class String
{
public:
 String();
 String(const String &c);
 String(const char * c);
 String(std::list<char> c); // No idea why someone would have this constructor, but it was included in the original ...
 ~String();

 String& operator = (const String &c);

 const char *c_str();
private:
 unsigned int length;
 char* entries;
};
```

Comment: I used the constructor String::String(std::List<char> &copy); because when the string is being read, I would store them in a list and afterward initialize the String by the characters in the List.

Comment: There are MUCH better ways of doing that.  You could use a vector to store the characters, or better yet, read from the istream directly into your string class, or even better, use the std::string class (unless this is a homework assignment that requires you to write your own).

Comment: Yes, I am fetching the characters in the list using a function read_in(istream &input) and using the list for temporary storage. Actually, it is like an assignment since I am doing that on my own after following from a Data Structures book. I am not an IT guy :)

Comment: You should take a hard look at the `std::string` class as it will solve virtually all your issues with this in 1 fell swoop.